# select entire word in textarea with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a textarea and among free text input I insert some tags that are enclosed in `<tag>`. I'd like to be able to click on a tag (i.e.) within < > and select the whole tag in order to delete. the whole thing and not one character at a time.

```
<textarea>some text and <my tag> here</textarea>
```

I suppose I need to use some sort of regex check on click?

---

UPDATE:

OK, I'll try to modify this question. I'm not doing it to make it more difficult, it's just I keep brainstorming as well as I go.

Let's say I have my tags predefined and I put them in my textarea by clicking a  with corresponding ID:

```
var myTag1 = "my tag",
myTag2 = "another tag";

$("#tag1").text(myTag1);
$("#tag2").text(myTag2);

$(".tags").click(function () {
    var insertTag = $(this).text();
    $('#myTextArea').append(" &lt;" + insertTag + ">");
});

<div id="tag1" class="tags"></div>
<div id="tag2" class="tags"></div>

<textarea id="myTextArea"></textarea>
```

Now, let's say I composed a message and inserted either both tag1 and tag2 or just one. Is it possible to click on a tag insert within that textarea and delete that tag as well as surrounding < and > ?

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/2K2CX/2/

Comment: When you say 'the whole thing' you mean everything *including* the `<` and `>` or just the *text* portion `tag`?

Comment: Yes, everything between < and > whether one word or a phrase including <>.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<textarea id="textarea" style="width:500px;height:200px;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur <adipiscing> elit. Aliquam adipiscing feugiat vestibulum. <Proin risus massa>, cursus quis eleifend tristique, pharetra eget ligula. <Suspendisse potenti>. Etiam vel lectus ante. Fusce varius laoreet lobortis. Aliquam ornare dictum lacus, non pharetra mauris fringilla sit amet. Quisque accumsan viverra dui, non pellentesque arcu bibendum et. Sed vel odio in libero scelerisque posuere. Phasellus euismod leo non arcu vulputate in sollicitudin sem facilisis. Morbi et dui luctus sem molestie commodo ac vel justo.</textarea>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var textarea = document.getElementById("textarea");
    textarea.onclick = textarea_Click;

    function textarea_Click() {
        var caret = getCaretPosition(textarea);
        var text = textarea.value;
        var begin = caret - 1;
        while (begin >= 0) {
            if (text.charAt(begin) == '>') return;
            else if (text.charAt(begin) == '<') break;
            else begin--;
        }

        if (begin >= 0) {
            var end = caret;
            while (end < text.length) {
                if (text.charAt(end) == '>') break;
                else end++;
            }

            if (end < text.length)
                setSelection(textarea, begin, end);
        }
    }

    function getCaretPosition(el) {
        if (el.selectionStart) {
            return el.selectionStart;
        } else if (document.selection) {
            var r = document.selection.createRange();
            if (r == null) return 0;
            var re = el.createTextRange();
            var rc = re.duplicate();
            re.moveToBookmark(r.getBookmark());
            rc.setEndPoint('EndToStart', re);
            return rc.text.length;
        }
        return 0; 
    }

    function setSelection(el, begin, end) {
        if ("selectionStart" in el) {
            el.selectionStart = begin;
            el.selectionEnd = end + 1;
        } else if (document.selection) {
            var range = el.createTextRange();
            range.collapse(true);
            range.moveEnd('character', end + 1);
            range.moveStart('character', begin);
            range.select();
        }
    }
</script>
```

---

EDIT: Since you're using jQuery, the [fieldSelection plugin](http://laboratorium.0xab.cd/jquery/fieldselection/0.1.0/test.html) might make things a lot cleaner.

As for a simple regex solution, nothing immediately comes to mind, but I'm also no regexpert :)

EDITED AGAIN: I changed my original code so that it now supports IE. Tested in Firefox, Chrome, and IE 6/7/8.

Comment: Holy smokes! Yes, I need to support multiple browsers, but from your question I suspect it might not be as straight forward, hah? I just updated my initial question, which I think should make it a bit simpler, sorry about the confusion.

Comment: Yes, I do use jQuery and I think while my learning curve is still pretty steep it is easier than straight JS, I think.

Comment: The jsfiddle page seems to be working OK for me. Are you not seeing what you intended? Maybe I misunderstood your original question...

Comment: No, it works great in jsfiddle, but I only tested in FF so far. I am open to plug-ins as long as they are not very bloated. I looked at that plug-in but don't really understand how to use it.

Comment: Do you think it is easier if I used predefined inserts, like in my updated example above? That way I probably won't even need regex. I can compare to the var value, just not sure how :)

Comment: Just tested in IE, and it didn't work... :( But works great in FF, Safari and Opera.

Comment: I just edited my answer. The code should work in IE 6/7/8 now too. Give it a try!

Comment: As for having pre-defined tags: You could certainly do this a different way with a pre-defined tags, but I still don't think it will end up being a super simple 5-line solution. No matter how you do it, the trick is figuring out whether or not the caret is in the middle of one of the tags, and unfortunately, to the best of my knowledge, that requires a fair bit of JavaScript. I'd love to be proven wrong, though!

Comment: Thanks @Michael. Yes, this is a complex issue. Appreciate you giving it a crack!