# How to Select a Word from a string in textarea on mouse single click on the word

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a string in a html textarea.Using jquery is it possible to select a word from a string by just single clicking on the word.

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [select entire word in textarea with jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5170502/select-entire-word-in-textarea-with-jquery)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not exactly what you want, but i hope it helps you in some way...I got this from the net.

```js
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('body').on('click', 'textarea', function() {
      textarea_Click(this);
    });
  });

  function textarea_Click(e) {
    var caret = getCaretPosition(e);
    var text = e.value;
    var begin = caret - 1;
    while (begin >= 0) {
      if (text.charAt(begin) == '}') return;
      else if (text.charAt(begin) == '{') break;
      else begin--;
    }

    if (begin >= 0) {
      var end = caret;
      while (end < text.length) {
        if (text.charAt(end) == '}') break;
        else end++;
      }

      if (end < text.length)
        setSelection(begin, end, e);
    }
  }

  function getCaretPosition(textarea) {
    if (textarea.selectionStart) {
      return textarea.selectionStart;
    } else {
      // TODO: Handle IE ugliness on your own :)
      return 0;
    }
  }

  function setSelection(begin, end, textarea) {
    if ("selectionStart" in textarea) {
      textarea.selectionStart = begin;
      textarea.selectionEnd = end + 1;
    } else if (document.selection) {
      // TODO: Handle IE ugliness on your own :)
      return;
    }
  }
```

```css
textarea {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea>Our doubts are traitors, {and} make us lose the {good} we oft might win, by {fearing} to attempt.</textarea>
```